# How do I get WebGuy->fillField for <input type="email"> in Codeception acceptance test?

Tags: unit-testing, automation, acceptance-testing, codeception, acceptance

In Codeception the fillField works fine when I have 
`<input type="text" name="email">` but it does not work when `<input type="email" name="email">`

I have tried with the following code

```
$I->fillField('input[name=email]', 'user@domain.com');
```

Also With `$I->fillField('email', 'user@domain.com');`

But it does not work. I am getting the following error.

***ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible***

Comment: BTW, I am using WebDriver and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested on email field still If it doesn't work, you can choose some work arounds like below: -

(1) Using JS

```
$I->executeJS('window.document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='###value###'');
```

(2) Using low level webdriver code : -

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Webdriver $webdriver) {
    $webdriver->findElement('###XPATH###')->sendKeys(###value###);
});
```

Again, if you get any Codeception specific issues, please raise them  [here](http://www.phptest.club)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer actually, Now I can target any form element by XPATH without running executeInSelenium

So in chrome / firefox I inspect the dom and right-click and copy the xpath,

as an example:
`$I->fillField('//*[@id="register-form"]/fieldset/section[3]/div/div/label/input', 'user@domain');`

And it works great for other form elements too